Multiplying two rasters having different cell sizes in R
I want to multiply Landsat 30m resolution image with an ERA5 raster of about 25km resolution. I can downscale ERA5 to 30m but it would increase processing. I am just wondering is it possible that whichever 30m cells overlap with 25km cell, these 30m cells get multiplied by single value from 25km cell.
library(terra)
### 1st raster
ETrF <- rast(ncols=4, nrows=4, xmin=73, xmax=75, ymin=31, ymax=33)
### 2nd raster
ET0 <- rast(ncols=2, nrows=2, xmin=73, xmax=75, ymin=31, ymax=33)
### Random values assigned to both rasters
values(ETrF) <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8)
values(ET0) <- c(5,1,2,4)

### Now 1st cell of ET0 (value: 5) will overlap with 1st,2nd,5th and 6th cells (values: 0.1,0.2,0.5,0.6) 
### of ETrF.Is it possible that 5 gets multiplied with 0.1,0.2,0.5 and 0.6 and final output 
### keeps ETrFs resolution.

ETa <- ETrF*ET0.....?


Not an expert, but have you read the docs to raster::resample? Would (ET0v1 = raster::resample(ET0, ETrF)); ETa = ETrF * ET0v1; par(mfrow = c(1L, 3L)); X = lapply(list(ETrF, ET0, ETa), plot) (or in different order) do what you are after?

A reason for not implementing that is that you need to chose how to resample the data; x * y cannot capture that.
In your case, the default bilinear interpolation is probably the most reasonable option when using resample (unless you need a more sophisticated methods that use elevation and other covariables).
But it does not give the same results as with the extract method. (you need to use resample( , method="near") for that). With the toy data, you can also use disagg.
If you want to use the extract route, that can be made much more efficient by avoiding the coercion to sf, at least for this toy example:
fastextr <- function(coarse, fine, method="simple") {
    xy <- crds(fine)
    value <- extract(coarse, xy, method=method) * values(fine)
    rasterize(xy, fine, value)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    "res" = terra::resample(ET0, ETrF, "near", threads = TRUE) * ETrF,
    "mutat" = extract_mutate_rasterize(ET0, ETrF),
    "disagg" = terra::disagg(ET0, 2) * ETrF,
    "fextr" = fastextr(ET0, ETrF), 
    times = 50
) 

#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr     min      lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
#    res  6.2586  6.4362  6.948614  6.67490  6.8020 21.1767    50
#  mutat 38.6304 39.4301 40.627638 40.08070 41.1208 58.3876    50
# disagg  4.5824  4.6490  5.158002  4.77420  4.9126 21.7821    50
#  fextr  7.9329  8.1154  8.468164  8.44225  8.6150 11.1409    50

So your best option is to use bilinear resampling
bres <- terra::resample(ET0, ETrF, "bilinear", threads = TRUE) * ETrF

The same result can be obtained with bilinear extract
bextr <- fastextr(ET0, ETrF, "bilinear")

This extract approach is not much slower than the resample approach for this example. But I would not use the extract method because it may cause problems with memory allocation if you are using large raster data.

Thanks for pointing out that method = "bilinear" would be the default when using project() here - and therefore the result will be a different one compared to extract_mutate_rasterize().

Thanks for pointing to the use of crds, as it's way more efficient!

Thank you very much. What I am trying to do is use the METRIC model's ETrF as crop coefficient (Kc) and multiplying it with reference ET to get actual ET. Problem: I don't have access to observed weather data so I thought of using Climate Models data instead. Yes probably, resampling with nearest neighbour approach is best as it retains the original value of cell for all the downscaled cells in that region. I am avoiding extra processing otherwise I know I can downscale climate data in ArcGIS using krigging and DEM as co-variable.

You could do that in R as well. See terra::interpolate

I believe resample is the way to go, maybe using the threads argument can improve efficiency.
An alternative solution would be extracting the values from ET0 using the centroids from ETrF, but hard to know how much it will improve efficiency. I would have to benchmark it with a larger data set.
Here is a possible approach using your example data.
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

ETrF_c <- st_as_sf(as.points(ETrF, values = TRUE)) # ETrF centroids

ETrF_new <- st_as_sf(extract(ET0, ETrF_c, bind = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(value = lyr.1*lyr.1.1) %>% 
  rasterize(., ETrF, field = 'value')

plot(ETrF_new)



Thank you too. Your solution works very well. I highly appreciate the quick response and your effort.

Since everybody seems to agree on resample(), this should be part of the answer from my point of view, so here is a little demonstrator using {terra}:
ET0_resampled <- resample(ET0, ETrF)
ET0_resampled
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 4, 4, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : 73, 75, 31, 33  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        : lyr.1 
#> min value   :     1 
#> max value   :     5

ET0_resampled * ETrF
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 4, 4, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#> extent      : 73, 75, 31, 33  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#> source(s)   : memory
#> name        : lyr.1 
#> min value   : 0.275 
#> max value   : 3.200

From a performance point of view, I can't really recommend using the extract-mutate-rasterize approach - as creative as this may be:
extract_mutate_rasterize <- function(coarse, fine) {
  
  # centroids
  fine_c <- as.points(fine, values = TRUE) %>% st_as_sf()
  
  res <- extract(coarse, fine_c, bind = TRUE) %>% 
    st_as_sf() %>% 
    mutate(value = lyr.1 * lyr.1.1) %>% 
    rasterize(., fine, field = 'value')
  
  res
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark("terra::resample(threads = TRUE)" = terra::resample(ET0, ETrF, threads = TRUE) * ETrF,
                               "extract_mutate_rasterize @ FAmorim" = extract_mutate_rasterize(ET0, ETrF),
                                times = 500)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq
#>     terra::resample(threads = TRUE)  5.9338  6.40875  7.625009  7.1113  8.21190
#>  extract_mutate_rasterize @ FAmorim 36.2193 41.15560 47.067254 45.7299 50.00195
#>       max neval
#>   21.1489   500
#>  157.1793   500

... and I really can't imagine this scales very well with increasing number of cells.
